# Removing with ->outertext is not removing

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have the following code:

```
<div id="coursename">
  <h1>My Golf Club<br>
  <span class="courseregion">My Region</span></h1>
</div>
```

What I want to do is get the course name and it's region. Separately. Now, because the region is inside the `#coursename` element, I firstly want to get `.courseregion`, then remove it so I don't end up with `My Golf ClubMy Region`

This is what I'm trying but it still returns both together:

```
$course_region = $html->find('.courseregion', 0);

$region_to_use = $course_region; // stored

$course_region->outertext = ""; // get rid of course region

$course_name = $html->find('#coursename', 0);

echo $course_name->plaintext; // returns -> My Golf ClubMy Region
```

Where am I going wrong? Any ideas?

**UPDATE** I cannot modify the html, it is what it is

Comment: I'm a little confused, where do you want to do this? Why does your server load in already formed HTML and then try to modify it? Why not just generate the HTML you need, using the data that formed this HTML, instead? And if you're scraping, why not just grab `"#coursename h1"`, why remove a span that has nothing to do with the text you wanted?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans h1 would return 'My Golf ClubMy Region'.  He needs to break them apart.

Comment: Then still: why try to remove the element? Just take the string you get from `"#coursename h1 span"` (say, as `$a`), and the string you get from `"#coursename h1"` (say, `$b`), and just do str_replace($b, "", $a)`

Comment: updated the question, I should have maybe made it clearer

Comment: What is the php variable that is echoed out to display 'My Golf Club' and 'My Region' and why can't you re-use that variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just work with the strings, don't try to modify the HTML. In this case:

```
// the element you're showing has an id, so there is only ever one
$cn = $html->find('#coursename');
$h1 = $cn->find('h1');

// get both the "full" text, and the "text we don't want":
$a = $h1.innertext;
$b = $h1->find('span').innertext;

// now we just remove $b from $a.
// We don't need to edit the HTML to achieve that:
$actual_text = str_replace($b, '', $a);
```

Comment: Yeah I came up with that too but am interested why the parser doesn't work as it should as that could get complicated pretty fast.

Comment: not with well-formed HTML. The HTML you're showing is all kinds of wrong. `<br>` has been deprected for a long time, for instance, and well formed semantic HTML would have that first bit inside the `<h1>` in a span as well, so it can be semantically extracted. If you in any way control the HTML you're reading in: worth fixing. If not: that's simply the downside of scraping bad source code.

Comment: Yeah I get that, the parser should ignore bad code though, it's not relevant - anyway, appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

It's because simple isn't updating plaintext (it's a bug):

```
$html = <<<EOF
<div id="coursename">
  <h1>My Golf Club<br>
  <span class="courseregion">My Region</span></h1>
</div>
EOF;

$doc = str_get_html($html);
$doc->find('.courseregion', 0)->outertext = "";

echo $doc->find('#coursename', 0)->plaintext . "\n";
//    My Golf Club    My Region   

$doc = str_get_html((string)$doc); // reload $doc (or switch to http://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/?source=directory)

echo $doc->find('#coursename', 0)->plaintext . "\n";
//    My Golf Club
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_replace and remove $region_to_use from $course_name->plaintext;

```
//this will remove $region_to_use from $course_name->plaintext
echo(substr_replace ($region_to_use, '', $course_name->plaintext);
```